# Cannot See Vertex paint in viewport shader

Tags: vertex-paint

I just started with blender and can't figure out how to view vertex paint in rendered viewport shader mode! this is really annoying and all I can find out is how to do it in older versions but I'm in 2.93.0 and those options are gone! please help and provide a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found it out,

1. go to shader editor
2. Click "add" and add a "Vertex Color"
3. click the grey box on the new vertex color and click "Col" or your colormap
4. Drag onto the circle next to "Color" in the vertex color map and drag it to the "Principled BSDF"
5. Wait A few seconds and Done!

I received this info after some research from here: https://youtu.be/7cphcAZ5ai8?t=106

Comment: Edit: drag it into the principled bsdf base color

Comment: the name of the node has changed to "Color Attribute"